# Where is the map reduce JAR for batch hbase indexing in a parcel-managed Cloudera environment?

Tags: solr, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to run some batch indexing on my parcel-managed Cloudera-CDH 4.7 environment.  The directions for [Search 1.2](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Search/1.2.0/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_hbase_mapreduce_indexer_tool.html) and [Search 1.3](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Search/latest/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_hbase_batch_indexer.html) reference the file `/usr/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-*-job.jar` that I don't seem to have.  Where is this located in a parcel-managed environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a parcel manged enviroment the batch indexer jar is located at the following path:  `/opt/cloudera/parcels/SOLR/lib/hbase-solr/tools/hbase-indexer-mr-*-job.jar`